# Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions AppFabric cache admin command 'missing'

Tags: appfabric-cache

Trying to run Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions

But get the following error msg:

The term 'Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions' is not recognized as the name of a c
mdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the na
me, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:32
+ Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions
   :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I inadvertently installed v1.0 via an old Hanselman blog post.
After much confusion I uninstalled AppFabric 1.0 from my two test servers and installed AppFabric 1.1.
Now I see Update-CacheHostAllowedVersions as an available cmdlet.
Which I no longer need since my client dlls are in sync with my server's version of AppFabric.